# Refreshing credentials/configuration in Azure VM scale sets

Tags: azure, configuration, devops, azure-vm-scale-set

What is the recommended approach to automatically refresh credentials or application configuration in an Azure VM scale set?

### Scenario

I have a horizontally-scalable application hosted in Azure that receives real-time streaming data. I've configured a simple CI/CD pipeline that builds a custom immutable image with the application binaries/libraries and then publishes it to an image gallery. From there, it's deployed to a scale set with a load balancer frontend to distribute traffic across the instances. At creation time, each instance fetches an application configuration file from blob storage and credentials from key vault.

### Problem

When the application configuration or credentials are changed, those changes are not reflected in running instances until they are reimaged. As the application handles streaming data, I must manually effect a "rolling restart" by reimaging each instance one-by-one to ensure the application remains available while all instances are updated to the newest configuration.

### Question

Azure provides a native "rolling upgrade" functionality to handle changes to scale set properties. I already use this when deploying new images, and it works very well. However, changes to the application configuration in blob storage or credentials in key vault obviously do not trigger a change to scale set properties. Is there a way to effect the same "rolling upgrade" process to account for external changes, without having to manually cycle through the instances and reimage them? Alternatively, is there a better approach to managing application configuration/credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have scripts to fetch the application configuration file from blob storage and credentials from the key vault. It's recommended to uses the [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#already-provisioned) to run those scripts on Azure VM scale sets. The Custom Script Extension downloads and executes scripts on Azure VMs. This extension is useful for post-deployment configuration, software installation, or any other configuration/management task.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Unfortunately Azure extensions also require the Azure Linux Agent (waagent) to be installed. I currently provision with pure cloud-init, and was hoping to avoid having to add the waagent package, as it tacks on about 100MB and a number of additional dependencies. I've tried to use cloud-init custom data in the same manner, but changes to the custom data definition don't trigger scale set updates. Are you aware of any other possible solutions?

Comment: As cloud-init runs during the initial boot process, it does not trigger the scale set updates. In this case, you also could refer to [Install applications with OS update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-deploy-app#install-applications-with-os-updates) as the above links mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! I ended up deploying the Azure Linux Agent and using a simple custom script extension that clears the cloud-init data and reboots the VM. That allows me to toggle the [ForceUpdateTag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#how-to-run-custom-script-more-than-once-with-cli) on the extension to trigger a rolling reboot/re-provision.